# Knockout.js data-bind attribute causes html validation warning

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm using the HTML Validator firefox add-on and when I go to the home page of http://knockoutjs.com/, I get warnings about the `data-bind` attribute (for the Live Example):

Examples:

`<select>` proprietary attribute "data-bind"

`<button>` proprietary attribute "data-bind"

I also get errors regarding the `data-bind` attribute when submitting the URL at http://validator.w3.org/.

I know this html attribute is used by knockout.js to do some data binding, but can we conclude that this approach does not follow the HTML specification? Does knockout.js follow the spirit of valid HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are HTML 5 custom attributes. Try to validate against HTML 5 specs and you should get an ok on the validation.

But since long you have been able to use custom attributes as you see fit although it may have violated strict HTML 4 specs.

Comment: Ok, the knockout.js website uses the strict declaration, so that explains the warnings.