# Knockout JS data-bind values on multiple lines - HTML5 validation warning

Tags: knockout.js, visual-studio-2012

Warning received in VS2012:

```
Validation (HTML5): If this attribute value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match.
```

When splitting data-bind parameter values onto more than one line, seems to be only when one of them contains a certain condition e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/ - splitting line 37 onto two lines...

from: `<button data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>`

to: 
`<button data-bind='click: save,`

`enable: contacts().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>`

Any idea why this is triggered?

If I switch to HTML4 validation I get a warning about data-bind, same as here: [Knockout.js data-bind attribute causes html validation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431767/knockout-js-data-bind-attribute-causes-html-validation-warning)

I either have some really long lines of HTML or this warning. Anything else I can do to work around this?

Comment: This really seems like a bad warning in VS. There is nothing wrong with splitting things up like that, and it improves readability in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you put the whole attribute on one line?

```
<button
    data-bind='click: save, enable: contacts().length > 0'>
    Save to JSON
</button>
```

That's a bit of an improvement, though not much!

Comment: Yeah this may be all I can do, it is at the point where this approach still goes completely off screen on a 1920x1080 resolution :)

Comment: Yeah, that's not good! You could put the enable test into a computed observable, that would save a bit more space.

Answer (score 0):

While VS notice is pointless, sometimes knockout might complain that it cannot parse bindings. In such case, enclose identifiers (`click`, `enable` etc.)in single quote, ie:

```html
<button
    data-bind="
        'click': save, 
        'enable': contacts().length > 0
    ">
    Save to JSON
</button>
```